# Modules update issue

Tags: updating

I've been having problems to update modules through the admin feature.

I tried googling a lot about this issue but I always get other kind of module update issue but if this is answered elsewhere, please point me to it.

I don't recall how this started, I think around Drupal 7.18/7.19

What happens is that I get a daily email (from the cron) saying there are updates available. I go to ../admin/reports/updates/update, check all modules, update them all successfully. Then Drupal offers me to run updates in maintenance mode but when I click continue I get back to .../admin/update/ready with the site in maintenance mode activated. I retry and get back to the same page.

I run update.php and get "no pending update". Then I go to status report and all the modules appear updated but after a cron run, all the modules "go back" to the old version.

All this still happens after updating to 7.20

Any ideas?